# Angular ui-router `template:` works, but not `templateUrl:`

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

Using `template: 'test',` works, but replacing that line with `templateUrl: 'static/app/partials/filter.html',` does not do anything, I assume because the partial is never found (but haven't verified this). The path to `filter.html` is `Project/app/static/app/partials/filter.html`, where `Project` is located under `C:\Users\david\Dropbox\JetBrains\`

This is used in conjunction with a Django project, and I've been following the example set by a DjangoCon demonstration with Angular where their properly working templateUrl is `templateUrl: 'static/tweeter/partials/tweet-list.html',`

I've tried variations on the templateUrl in assumption that this is the problem, by removing and adding various layers of directories. If this is a directory path problem, what directory am I supposed to use as a reference?

Sorry I can't figure out how to link to plnkr, I'll just copy the code here:

index:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="ui-router@*" data-semver="0.2.15" src="http://rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.15/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="mapApp">
  <div ui-view>
    <p>test failed</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

partial:

```
<h1>test success</h1>
```

js:

```
angular
  .module('mapApp', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
      .state('test', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'filter.html',
      });
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

your templateUrl should be `templateUrl: 'partials/filter.html'` only

Comment: Tried that just now, it didn't work. How are we supposed to come up with the correct directory, i.e. what is the templateUrl in relation to?

Comment: make a plnkr plz to illustrate your problem

Comment: `WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.` that's the only thing in console. Working on the plnkr, haven't used it before

Comment: Couldn't figure out how to link to plnkr so pasted code in OP, but I can't even get `template:` to work on plnkr (which works in my local project)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95042/discussion-between-macrog-and-vandidant).

Answer (score 0):

Make your paths relative to wherever your JS file is located. Also do you see something in the browser's console.

Comment: I tried putting them in the same directory and using `templateUrl: 'test.html'` still no dice. Nothing relevant to the error, just `WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.`

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem with a Django project, but it worked after setting the `templateUrl` path to start from the project root directory. Try `templateUrl: '/app/static/app/partials/filter.html'`. Hope that works!

Answer (score 0):

template String works fine but not templateUrl

I am also facing issue with templateUrl:

below is error on chrome console

```
angular.js:14525 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.error (angular.js:14525)
    at angular.js:11008
    at invokeLinkFn (angular.js:10428)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:9815)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:9055)
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js:8920)
    at lazyCompilation (angular.js:9311)
    at boundTranscludeFn (angular.js:9098)
    at controllersBoundTransclude (angular.js:9865)
    at update (angular-route.js:1172) "<!-- ngView: -->"
```